# Attach a Lambda@edge function to an existing Amazon Cloudfront distribution using Terraform

Tags: aws-lambda, terraform, amazon-cloudfront, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to update a Cloudfront distribution with a Lambda function using Terraform. Cloudfront has already been set up and I can't tear it down each time I deploy.

Is there a way to attach a Lambda function using Terraform without having to specify it in the creation of the Cloudfront instance?

Comment: Why do you think it would tear down your CloudFront distribution when you change the Lambda function? Would it be possible for you to include your Terraform code as a [mcve] that shows that a change to the Lambda function causes this replacement?

Comment: So currently I attach the Lambda function manually. I'm not at my work laptop but I'm using https://github.com/operatehappy/terraform-aws-cloudfront-website to spin up a static site. I know I can create my own and specify the lambda functions in the Cloudfront distribution code block in my Terraform script but was hoping there was maybe a way to use this and attach the function after. After all these projects are probably configured better than I ever could given the time-frames I have

Comment: You could fork that module and then add the configuration and that would then work. Then if you want to rewrite it later you can either keep the resource addresses the same or move the state around to match your refactored resource addresses.